# SHGetPathFromIDList does not return pathnames with leading periods

Tags: worksheet-function

I have some Excel x64 VBA code that gets MP3 files, along with track#, size, length, etc., and puts them in some worksheets.  The basic code came from John Walkenbach's page and can be found here: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/mp3_file_lister/.  I have modified it to run in 64-bit Excel by adding the PtrSafe keyword in the function declarations and changing some data types from Long to either LongLong or LongPtr (and maybe a few others).  The code works wonderfully with one not too minor exception, it will not return any files in folders that contain leading periods.  For example, I have an album by .38 Special ripped using WMP.  The folder is: D:\Users\username\Music\Music.38 Special\Rock & Roll Strategy...  This path does not appear in the list generated.  I also have: D:\Users\username\Music\Music\Norah Jones...Featuring Nora Jones... and this folder is missing, too (the trailing ellipses represent the list of songs) .  I have contacted John Walkenbach via email, and he has no idea why this is happening either.

Here is the code as I've modified it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Sht1Row As Integer
Dim Sht2Row As Integer

' By John Walkenbach
' Maybe be distributed freely, but not sold

'API declarations
Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As LongPtr, ByVal pszPath As String) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As LongPtr

Public Type BROWSEINFO
  hOwner As LongPtr
  pidlRoot As LongPtr
  pszDisplayName As String
  lpszTitle As String
  ulFlags As LongPtr
  lpfn As LongPtr
  lParam As LongPtr
  iImage As LongPtr
End Type

Sub GetAllFiles()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Directory As String
    Dim lastRow1C As Integer
    Dim lastRow2C As Integer
    Dim lastRow1D As Integer
    Dim lastRow2D As Integer

    Msg = "Select the directory that contains the MP3 files. All subdirectories will be included."
    Directory = GetDirectory(Msg)
    If Directory = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(Directory, 1)  "\" Then Directory = Directory & "\"
        With Sheet1
            lastRow1C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRow1C  lastRow2D Then
            .Range("D" & lastRow2D, "F" & lastRow2D).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D" & lastRow2D, "F" & lastRow2C)
        End If
        .Range("E2:E" & lastRow2C).Copy
        .Range("A2:A" & lastRow2C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Columns("A:J").Sort key1:=Range("G2"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("H2"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Range("A1").Select
    End With

    With Sheet1
        Worksheets("Music_Library_Full").Activate
        lastRow1C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRow1D = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow1C > lastRow1D Then
            .Range("D" & lastRow1D, "F" & lastRow1D).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D" & lastRow1D, "F" & lastRow1C)
        End If
        .Range("E2:E" & lastRow1C).Copy
        .Range("A2:A" & lastRow1C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         Columns("A:J").Sort key1:=Range("G2"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("H2"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Range("A1").Select
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetDirectory(Optional Msg) As String
    Dim bInfo As BROWSEINFO
    Dim path As String
    Dim r As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim pos As Integer
'   Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0&
'   Title in the dialog
    If IsMissing(Msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Select a folder."
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg
    End If
'   Type of directory to return
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1
'   Display the dialog
    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)
'   Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetDirectory = ""
    End If
End Function

Public Sub RecursiveDir(ByVal currdir As String)
    Dim Dirs() As Variant
    Dim NumDirs As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim PathAndName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim TrackNum As Variant
    Dim Genre As String
    Dim Duration As Variant
    Dim FileSize As Variant

'   Make sure path ends in backslash
    If Right(currdir, 1)  "\" Then currdir = currdir & "\"

'   Put column headings on active sheet
Worksheets("Music_Library_Full").Activate
    Cells(1, 1) = "Artist & Filename Lookup"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Filename Lookup"
    Cells(1, 3) = "Full Pathname"
    Cells(1, 4) = "Artist"
    Cells(1, 5) = "Artist & Filename"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Filename"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Path"
    Cells(1, 8) = "Track#"
    Cells(1, 9) = "Duration"
    Cells(1, 10) = "Size"
    Range("1:1").Font.Bold = True
    Range("1:1").Font.Italic = True
    Range("1:1").Font.Name = "Consolas"

Worksheets("Best_Greatest").Activate
    Cells(1, 1) = "Artist & Filename Lookup"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Filename Lookup"
    Cells(1, 3) = "Full Pathname"
    Cells(1, 4) = "Artist"
    Cells(1, 5) = "Artist & Filename"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Filename"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Path"
    Cells(1, 8) = "Track#"
    Cells(1, 9) = "Duration"
    Cells(1, 10) = "Size"
    Range("1:1").Font.Bold = True
    Range("1:1").Font.Italic = True
    Range("1:1").Font.Name = "Consolas"

'   Get files
    FileName = Dir(currdir & "*.*", vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(FileName)  0
      If Left$(FileName, 1)  "." Then 'Current dir
        PathAndName = currdir & FileName
        If (GetAttr(PathAndName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
          'store found directories
           ReDim Preserve Dirs(0 To NumDirs) As Variant
           Dirs(NumDirs) = PathAndName
           NumDirs = NumDirs + 1
        Else
            If UCase(Right(FileName, 3)) = "MP3" Then
                PathName = currdir 'path
                FileName = FileName 'filename
                TrackNum = FileInfo(currdir, FileName, 26) 'track
                Duration = FileInfo(currdir, FileName, 27) 'duration
                FileSize = Application.Round(FileLen(currdir & FileName) / 1024, 0) 'size
                'Application.StatusBar = Row
                If InStr(1, LCase(PathName), LCase("Best of"), vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, LCase(PathName), LCase("Greatest"), vbTextCompare) Then
                    'Sht2Row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) + 1
                    Worksheets("Best_Greatest").Activate
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 2) = FileName
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 3) = PathName & FileName
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 7) = PathName
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 8) = TrackNum
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 9) = Duration
                    Cells(Sht2Row, 10) = FileSize
                    Sht2Row = Sht2Row + 1
                Else
                    'Sht1Row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) + 1
                    Worksheets("Music_Library_Full").Activate
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 2) = FileName
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 3) = PathName & FileName
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 7) = PathName
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 8) = TrackNum
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 9) = Duration
                    Cells(Sht1Row, 10) = FileSize
                    Sht1Row = Sht1Row + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    ' Process the found directories, recursively
    For i = 0 To NumDirs - 1
        RecursiveDir Dirs(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function FileInfo(path, FileName, item) As Variant
    Dim objShell As IShellDispatch4
    Dim objFolder As Folder3
    Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem2

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(path)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FileName)
    FileInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, item)

    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
End Function
```

If anyone has any idea how to modify this so that pathnames containing a leading period as any part of the path can be returned, I'd be very glad to see it.  I'd just rename those particular paths by removing the leading periods, but I'm afraid WMP will just one day put everything back the way it was (has happened before).  Also, if you pick the actual folder in the BrowseForFolder API, that folder with the leading periods actually makes it into the sheet, but of course, only that folder.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line in your code sample:

If Left$(FileName, 1)  "." Then 'Current dir

Since the current directory is defined as a single '.' character, and this code only checks the initial character, it drops out before recursively examining it. Change the condition to **check the length of the string** as well as the initial character, e.g.

If (Left$(FileName, 1) = "." And FileName.Length = 1)  Then 'Current dir

N.B. This code has not been tested; I hope it works for your use.

Comment: That originally said: "If Left$(FileName, 1) <> "." then".  It would appear to be a test to see if the code is picking up the root and subdirectory entries of the folder it's in.  I've tried some variations like > 2; <> "." or ".."; nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by separating the test for root and subdirectory into separate IF statements, i.e.:

```
    If filename <> "." Then
        If filename <> ".." Then
            *Code here*
        End If
    End If
```

Might be clunky, but it works.

The original If statement was:

```
If filename <> "." or filename <> ".." Then
```

This never worked. But then it occurred to me that maybe I needed to use a NAND statement.  NAND = Not And.  So I tried this:

```
if Not filename = "." And Not Filename = ".." then
```

This actually worked and seems to execute more rapidly than the earlier solution.

Comment: BillOer - I was excited to run across this posting of yours, and so glad to learn that someone had upgraded Walkenbach's MP3FileLister code. However, your code snippet above doesn't compile for numerous reasons - it appears that several of the equals symbols in IF statements are missing, as well as elsewhere. I also assume that there are some prerequisites for a successful completion, including pre-created worksheets. Is there any chance you would be willing to post your final file, or revise the code in your original post? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
' By John Walkenbach
' Maybe be distributed freely, but not sold

Sub GetAllFiles()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Directory
    Msg = "Select the directory that contains the MP3 files. All subdirectories will be included."
    Set Directory = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With Directory
        .Title = Msg
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Directory = .SelectedItems.item(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then Directory = Directory & "\"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells.Clear

    '   Put column headings on active sheet
    Cells(1, 1) = "Path"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Filename"
    Cells(1, 3) = "FullPath"
    Cells(1, 4) = "Artist"
    Cells(1, 5) = "Album"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Title"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Track#"
    Cells(1, 8) = "Genre"
    Cells(1, 9) = "Duration"
    Cells(1, 10) = "Year"
    Cells(1, 12) = "Size"
    Range("1:1").Font.Bold = True

    Call RecursiveDir(Directory)
End Sub

Public Sub RecursiveDir(ByVal currdir As String)
    Dim Dirs() As Variant
    Dim NumDirs As Long
    Dim filename As String
    Dim PathAndName As String
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim Row As Variant

'   Make sure path ends in backslash
    If Right(currdir, 1) <> "\" Then currdir = currdir & "\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Get files
    filename = Dir(currdir & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(filename) <> 0
    DoEvents
      If Not filename = "." And Not filename = ".." Then 'Current dir
        PathAndName = currdir & filename
        If (GetAttr(PathAndName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            'store found directories
            ReDim Preserve Dirs(0 To NumDirs) As Variant
            Dirs(NumDirs) = PathAndName
            NumDirs = NumDirs + 1
        Else
            If UCase(Right(filename, 3)) = "MP3" Then
                Row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
                Cells(Row, 1) = currdir 'path
                Cells(Row, 2) = filename 'filename
                Cells(Row, 3) = PathAndName
                Cells(Row, 4) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 20) 'artist
                Cells(Row, 5) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 14) 'album
                Cells(Row, 6) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 21) 'title
                Cells(Row, 7) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 26) 'track
                Cells(Row, 8) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 16) 'genre
                Cells(Row, 9) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 27) 'duration
                Cells(Row, 10) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 15) 'Year
                Cells(Row, 11) = FileInfo(currdir, filename, 5)
                Cells(Row, 12) = Application.Round(FileLen(currdir & filename) / 1024, 0) 'size
                Application.StatusBar = Row
            End If
        End If
    End If
        filename = Dir()
    Loop
    ' Process the found directories, recursively
    For i = 0 To NumDirs - 1
        RecursiveDir Dirs(i)
    Next i
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Function FileInfo(path, filename, item) As Variant
    Dim objShell As IShellDispatch4
    Dim objFolder As Folder3
    Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem2

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(path)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(filename)
    FileInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, item)

    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
End Function
```

Also, other fileinfo items: 27 = duration, 28 = bit rate, 26 = track number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add some information to your answer outlining the changes you made and why?

Comment: Aaron, thanks for the welcome.  Your question is a bit...er...complicated.  My original question was why folders with one or more leading periods was not being included in the file lister.  To that end the code I finally came up with to fix it was:

Comment: Sorry.  I hit >Enter< instead of >Shift-Enter< then took longer than 5 minutes to try and fix my error.
The original IF statement that was causing folders with one or more leading periods to be skipped was:
"If Left$(FileName, 1) <>  "." Then"
My original question was how to fix this.  I finally came up with the following IF statement:
"If Not filename = "." And Not filename = ".." Then"
which is basically a NAND statement.  This worked.  The rest of this most recent answer is John Walkenbach's code that doesn't include the API calls.  He hasn't posted this to his website, and I wish he would.